# How to make JavaC keep good class files when some input files are failing?

Tags: java, ant, javac

When one compiles *two* independent java files with **one javac call** their class files are either

1. *both* output to the output folder, on successful compile, or
2. *neither* class file is output, if one source file contains some syntax or other error.

How can we make JavaC keep the good class file?

In other words, how can we make Javac to behave in a *best effort* way?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with either:

1. Batch multiple calls to `javac`
2. Use another compiler, such as Eclipse's

As far as I can tell, the `failOnError` won't work as a flag for `javac` - only if you use Ant.

Comment: Even "failOnError" does not make the class files appear. It just says that the Ant build does not abort in case of failed input files.

Comment: @mgaert - Yes, this was my first answer on your question, but after reading it up i noticed that failOnError will just continue the build process (so, it will execute the rest of your targets), there is no connection to the compilation of your classes..